# ToDiscreteTimeModel fails following video

Tags: modeling, control-systems

Following the systems-modeling video [here](http://tinyurl.com/ovbw56t)

at about 15 min, 20 seconds in, the presenter (Bob Sanhedrick, I think) shows a model for an "Asteroids-game"-like 2D spacecraft.

The model is trivial:

```
dynamics = {m x''[t] == u1[t], m y''[t] == u2[t]}
```

or, in state-space form:

```
spacecraft = StateSpaceModel[
  dynamics, 
  {x[t], y[t]},
  {u1[t], u2[t]},
  {x[t], y[t]},
  t]
```

> ```
> {{{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, 
>  {{0, 0}, {1/m, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1/m}}, 
>  {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}}, 
>  {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}}
> ```

The next step is converting it to a discrete-time model (15:52 in the video):

```
spacecraftD = ToDiscreteTimeModel[spacecraft, 1, Method -> "ZeroOrderHold"]
```

This fails (even in the downloaded copy of the video's notebook -- it's not my typo):

> ```
> During evaluation of In[3]:= General::ivar: 0 is not a valid variable. >>
> During evaluation of In[3]:= General::ivar: 0 is not a valid variable. >>
> StateSpaceModel[{
>   {{1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}, 
>   {{1/(2 m), 0}, {1/m, 0}, {0, 1/(2 m)}, {0, 1/m}}, 
>   {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, 
>   Automatic}, 
>   $Failed, 
>   {\[FormalK]}, 
>   SamplingPeriod -> 1]
> ```

Fortunately, I can copy out the failed model explicitly, leaving out the `Automatic`, and reproduce the rest of the demonstration verbatim:

[image]

The question is "why did this fail, and what can I do to fix it." I read the documentation for `TransferFunctionModel` and tried a number of hacks, to no avail.  I'd like to know this so that as I go to more advanced models I don't get stuck with something that doesn't have so obvious a workaround.

Comment: works with Mma9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug. May be you can send report to [support@wolfram.com](http://support@wolfram.com). I do not why it fails. Hard to debug using Trace. But it should work as is. I verified it using Maple symbolic control system functions and here is the result.

I took Mathematica's A,B,C,D that came up from the state space, used them in Maple to create a state space, then converted it to discrete using same sample rate and zoh method, and it worked.

Then also obtained the transfer functions (2, since 2 inputs/outputs) in z domain. All works with no problem:

```
  dynamics = {m x''[t] == u1[t], m y''[t] == u2[t]}
  sys=StateSpaceModel[dynamics, {x[t], y[t]}, {u1[t], u2[t]}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
  ToDiscreteTimeModel[sys, 1, Method -> "ZeroOrderHold"]
     (*  General::ivar: 0 is not a valid variable. >>  *)
```

Now copied A,B,C,D to Maple and tried there:

```
  restart:
  alias(DS=DynamicSystems):
  alias(size=LinearAlgebra:-Dimensions);
  a:=Matrix([[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,0]]):
  b:=Matrix([[0,0],[1/m,0],[0,0],[0,1/m]]):
  c:=Matrix([[1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0]]):
  d:=Matrix([[0,0],[0,0]]):
  sys:=DS:-StateSpace(a,b,c,d);
  sysd:=DS:-ToDiscrete(sys,1,method=zoh);
  {sysd:-a,sysd:-b,sysd:-c,sysd:-d}; #print A,B,C,D in z spce
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sysdAstf:=DS:-TransferFunction(sysd):
sysdAstf:-tf; # extract transfer functions in z space
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

May be M got some problem because there is no stiffness terms in the differential equations, hence the second and fourth state derivatives have zero rows in the A matrix. I do not know.

Mathematica version 10, windows 7, Maple 18.01, windows 7

Comment: the matrices of the discrete-time model are correct. The problem is in handling of the variables.

Comment: Wolfram customer support confirmed it's a bug.

Answer (score 4):

The input form of $spacecraft$ is the following:

```
StateSpaceModel[{{{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 
0}}, 
 {{0, 0}, {1/m, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1/m}}, {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 
0}}, 
 {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}}, {{x[t], 0}, 
 Subscript[\[FormalX], 1], {y[t], 0}, Subscript[\[FormalX], 2]}, 
 {{u1[t], 0}, {u2[t], 0}}, Automatic, t, SamplingPeriod -> None, 
 SystemsModelLabels -> None]
```

Delete all but the first argument, to get this:

```
StateSpaceModel[{{{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 
0}}, 
 {{0, 0}, {1/m, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1/m}}, {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 
0}}, 
 {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}}]
```

`ToDiscreteTimeModel` will definitely work with the above input.

To programmatically achieve this, do:

```
spacecraft = StateSpaceModel[Normal@spacecraft]
```

The errors you are getting seems to be because `ToDiscreteTimeModel` is having trouble handling the variables in `StateSpaceModel`. These variables were introduced in v10 and are primarily for the nonlinear systems. Nevertheless, it should still handle the variables correctly and produce the following:

```
StateSpaceModel[{{{1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 
1}}, 
 {{1/(2*m), 0}, {1/m, 0}, {0, 1/(2*m)}, {0, 1/m}}, {{1, 0, 0, 
0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}}, 
 {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}}, Automatic, {{u1[\[FormalK]], 
  0}, {u2[\[FormalK]], 0}}, 
 {Subscript[\[FormalY], 1][\[FormalK]], 
Subscript[\[FormalY], 2][\[FormalK]]}, \[FormalK], 
SamplingPeriod -> 1, SystemsModelLabels -> None]
```

I thought this handled correctly in v10, but I can verify that it will be in the next release.